# Avoiding KeyError in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am validating my dataframe with below code,

```
df = df[(df[['name', 'issuer_id', 'service_area_id']].notnull().all(axis=1)) &
                ((df['plan_year'].notnull()) & (df['plan_year'].astype(str).str.isdigit()) & (df['plan_year'].astype(str).str.len() == 4)) &
                (df[['network_url', 'formulary_url', 'sbc_download_url', 'treatment_cost_calculator_url']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x.str.contains('\A(https?:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_])*(\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,5})(\.*.*)?\Z')) | x.isin(['nan'])).all(axis=1)) &
                (df[['promotional_label']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x.str.len <= 65) | x.isin(['nan'])).all(axis=1)) &
                # (df[['sort_rank_override']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x.str.isdigit()) | x.isin(['nan'])).all(axis=1)) &
                ((df['hios_plan_identifier'].notnull()) & (df['hios_plan_identifier'].str.len() >= 10) & (df['hios_plan_identifier'].str.contains('\A(\d{5}[A-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,7}-TMP|\d{5}[A-Z]{2}\d{3,7}(\-?\d{2})*)\Z'))) &
                (df['type'].isin(['MetalPlan', 'MedicarePlan', 'BasicHealthPlan', 'DualPlan', 'MedicaidPlan', 'ChipPlan'])) &
                (df['price_period'].isin(['Monthly', 'Yearly'])) &
                (df['is_age_29_plan'].astype(str).isin(['True', 'False', 'nan']))]
                # (df[['composite_rating']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x.str.isin(['True', 'False']) & x.isnotin(['nan'])).all(axis=1)))]
```

This would throw me

> KeyError: "['name'] not in index"

when the column is not present in my dataframe. I need to handle for all columns. How can I efficiently add a check to my above code which checks for validation only when the column is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
L = ['name', 'issuer_id', 'service_area_id']
cols = df.columns.intersection(L)

(df[cols].notnull().all(axis=1))
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'name':list('abcdef'),
         'plan_year':[2015,2015,2015,5,5,4],
})
print (df)
  name  plan_year
0    a       2015
1    b       2015
2    c       2015
3    d          5
4    e          5
5    f          4
```

Idea is create dictionary of valid values for each colum first:

```
valid = {'name':'a', 
        'issuer_id':'a',
        'service_area_id':'a',
        'plan_year':2015,
         ...}
```

Then filter new dictionary by missing columns and [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to original `DataFrame` and create new DataFrame:

```
d1 = {k: v for k, v in valid.items() if k in set(valid.keys()) - set(df.columns)}
print (d1)
{'issuer_id': 'a', 'service_area_id': 'a'}


df1 = df.assign(**d1)
print (df1)
  name  plan_year issuer_id service_area_id
0    a       2015         a               a
1    b       2015         a               a
2    c       2015         a               a
3    d          5         a               a
4    e          5         a               a
5    f          4         a               a
```

Last filter:

```
m1 = (df1[['name', 'issuer_id', 'service_area_id']].notnull().all(axis=1)) 
m2 = ((df1['plan_year'].notnull()) & 
      (df1['plan_year'].astype(str).str.isdigit()) & 
      (df1['plan_year'].astype(str).str.len() == 4))

df1 = df1[m1 & m2]
print (df1)
  name  plan_year issuer_id service_area_id
0    a       2015         a               a
1    b       2015         a               a
2    c       2015         a               a
```

Last you can remove helper columns:

```
df1 = df1[m1 & m2].drop(d1.keys(), axis=1)
print (df1)
  name  plan_year
0    a       2015
1    b       2015
2    c       2015
```

Comment: I have updated my question with complete validation that I have. Any field could be absent from my dataframe. How can I handle such a situation?

Comment: @user1896796 - so what if missing `plan_year` and there is conditions with it? If column missing, what need return from `df['plan_year'].astype(str).str.isdigit()` ? Like `True` ? Or False?

Comment: I tried to have my validation such that `plan_year` cannot be null , it should be a digit , and should be of length 4. Any of these if not satisfied it should not be included in my returned dataframe.

Comment: I could use intersection for lists . Anything simpler for single columns check ?

Comment: @user1896796 - unfortunately your cannot filtering non exist columns... So no idea for simplier solution :(

Comment: @user1896796 - So my solution only add all missing columns with valid values and filter is not changed. There is some problem with my solution?

Comment: No problem with your solution. I am trying this. I was thinking can we use methods  . Provide the check whether this column is present or not in that and do the validations there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319037/adding-a-error-log-message-row-in-pandas-dataframe . can you help me in this question.

Comment: Hi @jezrael . Like the way we are doing. `m1 = (df1[['name', 'issuer_id', 'service_area_id']].notnull().all(axis=1))` . How can we handle such kind of validations?? `if df['Col1'] is not empty:
    df['col2'] cannot be blank and 
    df['col3'] cannot be blank` . I have tried a lot but could not find a workaround for this.

Comment: @user1896796 - `m1 = (df1[['name', 'issuer_id', 'service_area_id']].notnull().all(axis=1))` not working? do you think blank like `NAN` or like empty space?

Comment: This is working fine. There are validations which are kind of not straight forward like this - `if df['Col1'] is not empty: df['col2'] cannot be blank and df['col3'] cannot be blank ` . How can I handle such situations?

Comment: @user1896796 - Sorry, not understand. In pandas working with arrays so output of `m1 = (df1[['name', 'issuer_id', 'service_area_id']].notnull().all(axis=1))` is array, so possible filtering. If use `if df['Col1'] is not empty:` it seems want working with scalar, what is possible like `if df['Col1'].notnull().all()`. But not sure if understand.

Comment: Can we discuss on chat please. Can you send me the chat room link ?

Comment: @user1896796 - Never do it, I have no idea how ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184483/discussion-between-user1896796-and-jezrael).

Comment: Hi Jezrael, continuation of the chat `index 0, 1,3, 5` should be True. Would be kind of easier if there were are way to get this using if else.

Comment: @user1896796 - use `m = df['min_group_price'].isnull() | df[['single_male','single_female']].notnull().all(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Add another variable called `columns` and filter it with the ones that exist in df:

```
columns = ['name', 'issuer_id', 'service_area_id']
existing = [i for i in columns if i in df.columns]
df = df[(df[existing]...
```

**EDIT**
You could also assign each condition to a variable and use it later like this:

```
cond1 = df['is_age_29_plan'].astype(str).isin(['True', 'False', 'nan']) if 'is_age_29_plan' in df.columns else True
```

Then, use the `cond1` in your filtering statement.

Comment: Can you check my updated question . Any field could be absent from my dataframe. How can I handle such a situation?

Comment: Could you provide code snippet how to use the cond1 in filtering?