# Adding a error log message row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Based on this answer,
[Avoiding KeyError in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299337/avoiding-keyerror-in-dataframe/53299375?noredirect=1#comment93481878_53299375), I am able to do my validations. But I need to keep a track as to which row is failing due to which validation condition.

Is there a way where I can add a new column and provide a fail message?

My code-

```
valid_dict = {'name': 'WI 80 INDEMNITY 18 OPTION 1 SILVER RX $10/45/90/25%',
                          'issuer_id': 484,
                          'service_area_id': 1,
                          'plan_year': 2018,
                          'network_url': np.nan,
                          'formulary_url': np.nan,
                          'sbc_download_url': np.nan,
                          'treatment_cost_calculator_url': np.nan,
                          'promotional_label': np.nan,
                          'hios_plan_identifier': '99806CAAUSJ-TMP',
                          'type': 'MetalPlan',
                          'price_period': 'Monthly',
                          'is_age_29_plan': False,
                          'sort_rank_override': np.nan,
                          'composite_rating': False,
                          }

            data_obj = DataService()
            hios_issuer_identifer_list = data_obj.get_hios_issuer_identifer(df)

            d1 = {k: v for k, v in valid_dict.items() if k in set(valid_dict.keys()) - set(df.columns)}
            df1 = df.assign(**d1)
            cols_url = df.columns.intersection(['network_url', 'formulary_url', 'sbc_download_url', 'treatment_cost_calculator_url'])
            m1 = (df1[['name', 'issuer_id', 'service_area_id']].notnull().all(axis=1))
            m2 = (df1[['promotional_label']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x.str.len <= 65) | x.isin(['nan'])).all(axis=1))
            m3 = (df1[cols_url].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x.str.contains('\A(https?:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_])*(\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,5})(\.*.*)?\Z')) | x.isin(['nan'])).all(axis=1))
            m4 = ((df1['plan_year'].notnull()) & (df['plan_year'].astype(str).str.isdigit()) & (df['plan_year'].astype(str).str.len() == 4))
            m5 = ((df1['hios_plan_identifier'].notnull()) & (df['hios_plan_identifier'].str.len() >= 10) & (df['hios_plan_identifier'].str.contains('\A(\d{5}[A-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,7}-TMP|\d{5}[A-Z]{2}\d{3,7}(\-?\d{2})*)\Z')))
            m6 = (df1['type'].isin(['MetalPlan', 'MedicarePlan', 'BasicHealthPlan', 'DualPlan', 'MedicaidPlan', 'ChipPlan']))
            m7 = (df1['price_period'].isin(['Monthly', 'Yearly']))
            m8 = (df1['is_age_29_plan'].astype(str).isin(['True', 'False', 'nan']))
            m9 = (df1[['sort_rank_override']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x.str.isdigit()) | x.isin(['nan'])).all(axis=1))
            m10 = (df1['composite_rating'].astype(str).isin(['True', 'False']))
            m11 = (df1['hios_plan_identifier'].astype(str).str[:5].isin(hios_issuer_identifer_list))

            df1 = df1[m1 & m2 & m3 & m4 & m5 & m6 & m7 & m8 & m9 & m10 & m11].drop(d1.keys(), axis=1)

            merged =  df.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), how='outer', indicator=True)
            merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only'].to_csv('logs/invalid_plan_data.csv')

            return df1
```

Something like below-

```
 wellthie_issuer_identifier  issuer_name    ...     service_area_id     _error
0                   UHC99806  Fake Humana    ...                   1  failed on plan_year
```

Comment: It has been answered in the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53407115/1896796

Answer (score 2):

With `df1 = df1[m1 & m2 & m3 & m4 & m5 & m6 & m7 & m8 & m9 & m10 & m11].drop(d1.keys(), axis=1)` you are selecting the rows where none of your conditions failed. So clearly you will not have what you would like here, and that is ok, as this is the validated part which should not have errors.

You can get the errors by doing another selection before dropping the failed lines:

```
df_error = df1.copy()
df_error['error_message'] = ~m1
...
```

If the column had an error, you could define some error text to be displayed in the table:

```
df_error['failed_on_name'] = pd.where(m1, your_message_here)
```

If you want to display the error to a log you can loop over your error table and output your message (considering the first version with boolean values in the columns):

```
for _, row in df_error.iterrows():
    print (error_message(dict(row)))
```

So you will be able to process the rows with a function like this:

```
def error_message(row):
    row_desc = []
    error_msg = []
    for k, v in row.items():
        if isinstance(v, bool):
            if v:
                error_msg.append(k)
        else:
            row_desc.append(v)
    return 'Row ' + ' '.join(row_desc) + ' failed with errors: ' + ' '.join(error_msg)
```

Comment: How can I log with a message ? I want to indicate the user exactly what error has occurred. Ex: for m1 it would be something like `'name', or 'issuer_id', or 'service_area_id' has null values.`

Comment: Could you provide me a code snippet for this please.

Comment: @user1896796 please chech my refreshed answer.