# Finding out and logging the failed validation condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df,

```
      plan_year                                    name metal_level_name
0        20118            Gold Heritage Plus 1500 - 02             Gold
1         2018                                     NaN         Platinum
2         2018            Gold Heritage Plus 2000 - 01             Gold
```

I have put a data validation on `plan_year` and `name` columns like below,

```
m4 = ((df['plan_year'].notnull()) & (df['plan_year'].astype(str).str.isdigit()) & (df['plan_year'].astype(str).str.len() == 4))

m1 = (df1[['name']].notnull().all(axis=1))
```

I am getting the valid dataframe with below ,

```
df1 = df[m1 & m4]
```

I can get the rows which are not present in df1(the rows which are invalid)

```
merged = df.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), how='outer', indicator=True)
merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

I want to keep track as to which row failed due to which validation.

I want to get a dataframe with all the invalid data dataframe to look something like below-

```
 plan_year                                    name metal_level_name    Failed message
0        20118            Gold Heritage Plus 1500 - 02             Gold    Failed due to wrong plan_year
1         2018                                     NaN         Platinum     name column cannot be null
```

Can someone help me with this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with inverting boolena masks by `~`:

```
message1 = 'name column cannot be null'
message4 = 'Failed due to wrong plan_year'


df['Failed message'] = np.select([~m1, ~m4], [message1, message4], default='OK')
print (df)
   plan_year                          name metal_level_name  \
0      20118  Gold Heritage Plus 1500 - 02             Gold   
1       2018                           NaN         Platinum   
2       2018  Gold Heritage Plus 2000 - 01             Gold   

                  Failed message  
0  Failed due to wrong plan_year  
1     name column cannot be null  
2                             OK
```

---

```
df1 = df[df['Failed message'] != 'OK']
print (df1)
   plan_year                          name metal_level_name  \
0      20118  Gold Heritage Plus 1500 - 02             Gold   
1       2018                           NaN         Platinum   

                  Failed message  
0  Failed due to wrong plan_year  
1     name column cannot be null
```

EDIT: For multiple error messages create new `DataFrame` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and then matrix multiple it by columns names with separator by [`dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) and last remove separator from rigth side by [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
print (df)
   plan_year                          name metal_level_name
0      20118  Gold Heritage Plus 1500 - 02             Gold
1       2018                           NaN         Platinum
2       2018  Gold Heritage Plus 2000 - 01             Gold
1      20148                           NaN         Platinum

message1 = 'name column cannot be null'
message4 = 'Failed due to wrong plan_year'

df1 = pd.concat([~m1, ~m4], axis=1, keys=[message1, message4])
print (df1)
   name column cannot be null  Failed due to wrong plan_year
0                       False                           True
1                        True                          False
2                       False                          False
1                        True                           True


df['Failed message'] = df1.dot(df1.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
print (df)

   plan_year                          name metal_level_name  \
0      20118  Gold Heritage Plus 1500 - 02             Gold   
1       2018                           NaN         Platinum   
2       2018  Gold Heritage Plus 2000 - 01             Gold   
1      20148                           NaN         Platinum   

                                      Failed message  
0                      Failed due to wrong plan_year  
1                         name column cannot be null  
2                                                     
1  name column cannot be null, Failed due to wron...
```

---

```
df1 = df[df['Failed message'] != '']
print (df1)
   plan_year                          name metal_level_name  \
0      20118  Gold Heritage Plus 1500 - 02             Gold   
1       2018                           NaN         Platinum   
1      20148                           NaN         Platinum   

                                      Failed message  
0                      Failed due to wrong plan_year  
1                         name column cannot be null  
1  name column cannot be null, Failed due to wron...
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. In case, plan_year and name columns have invalid data , it is taking name message. Though I can work this. can we handle this situation?

Comment: One thing . like previously we were segregating with `df1 = df[df['Failed message'] != 'OK']`. How do we segregate now?

Comment: @user1896796 - Yes, edited answer 2 minutes ago, need `df1 = df[df['Failed message'] != '']`